# How to create a Protobuf request on NativeScript + Vue

Tags: nativescript, protocol-buffers, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to build an app around the [Google Transit API](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/) on NativeScript + Vue.js, and I'm struggling with the Protocol Buffers.

I do understand that Protobuf delivers binary data instead of the standard JSON object from the REST solutions; and as far as I can tell you need a middle library between your [Axio](https://github.com/axios/axios) request and the binary data delivered, something like [protobuf.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs), [google-protobuf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-protobuf), or [gtfs-realtime-bindings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gtfs-realtime-bindings), but it seems most of these solutions are for node.js.

Can anybody show me how to read such information delivered by Protobuf and storage it in a local object so you can work with it?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

NativeScript does not yet support binary over HTTP(S), so therefore it does not yet support protobuf directly from JS code.

With that said, it has been implemented and should [hopefully be coming in v6.3](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/7707#issuecomment-539590642).

See [my issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/7632) about adding Protobuf support, and [this PR](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/7707) for the implementation.

As far as an example, I give one in [my comment](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/7707#issuecomment-540609997) inside the PR (ex. is Angular but should give you the blueprint).

Comment: Bad luck for me. This is my first app on NativeScript-Vue and I still don't know enough to implement a go around to this problem. I guess I will have to wait until v6.3 is out and hopefully by then there will be examples in the documentation.

Thank you so much rynop for your detailed answer.